# Выдает ошибку при действие в контроллере

Tags: yii2

Что это такое? Что только уже не перепробовал, не получается убрать.

```
class CartController extends AppController
{
    public function actionAdd(){
        echo 'ok';
    }    
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый участник, пожалуйста, вставьте в вопрос stack trace в виде текста, а не изображения. [**Почему это нужно**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Спасибо.

Comment: что у вас на 18 строке в CartController.php ?

Comment: В 18 строке - echo 'ok';

Comment: значит у вас перед этим echo уже где-то есть вывод информации

Answer (score 1):

Заголовки нельзя отправлять после того, как уже было отправлено тело ответа. Вместо `echo 'ok';` надо использовать return. Конструкции echo, обычно, используют в файлах views/*. Вероятно стоит перечитать документацию еще раз.